# query in ADODB, dot il column name

Tags: sql, excel, adodb

I'm trying query excel file in which I have column name "sth sth." 
I get error cause ADODB doesn't like dot in name. So it should be like this:
SELECT `sth sth.` FROM.
I tried  SELECT `[sth sth.]` and  [`sth sth.`] and [sth sth.]
But it doesn't work. Please help. Getting rid of dot is not an option.

Comment: I meant that getting rid of dot is not an option in Excel file (field name). But system converts dot to #. So SELECT 'sth sth#' FROM ... is a solution to a problem